# How do I allow Templated Controls in a Control that doesn't inherit from WebControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

In all of the [examples of Templated server controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178657.aspx), the class to contain the Template inherit from the `CompositeControl` class, which itself inherits from the `WebControl` class.

In my application, I want to [use Templates in my Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx), but also to inherit from a different class, which does not inherit from either `CompositeControl` or `WebControl`.

"Template" could mean a whole host of things, but I am asking about code like this:

```
[
Browsable(false),
DefaultValue(null),
Description("The Template for the content of the Control"),
PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single),
]
public ITemplate Content { get; set; }
```

and ASP.NET code like this:

```
<prefix:CustomControl ID="Control1" runat="server">
    <Content>
        <asp:Literal ID="ExampleContent" runat="server" Text="Look at me" />
    </Content>
</prefix:CustomControl>
```

But, I have noticed that when I inherit from the `WebControl` class, the `ITemplate` variables in my object have the data I would expect, whereas if I don't inherit from `WebControl`, those variables have `NULL` data.

How do I use Template variables, but also inherit from any class of my choosing?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you must inherit from the `Control` class, but the magic happens with the `ParseChildren` attribute. To use Template variables, you must set the `ParseChildren` attribute to `true`.

```
[ParseChildren(true)] // Don't treat tags within the Control as properties, but as Controls
public class CustomControl : Control
{
    // ...
}
```

I found this after inspecting the `WebControl` class and [reading more about the attribute](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2008/07/27/parsechildren-persistchildren-persistencemode.innerproperty.aspx).

The `ParseChildren` attribute specifies how to interpret your ASP.NET code, whether the objects inside represent Controls (`ParseChildren(false)`) or Properties (`ParseChilren(true)`). Since your Template variables are actually Properties, you must set the `ParseChildren` attribute to `true`. Unfortunately, this also means that you can't mix Templated and non-Templated controls in your ASP.NET code, like this:

```
<prefix:CustomControl ID="Control1" runat="server">
    <Content>
        <asp:Literal ID="ExampleContent" runat="server" Text="Look at me" />
    </Content>
    <asp:Literal ID="ControlNonTemplate" runat="server" Text="This will not work (Parser error)" />
</prefix:CustomControl>
```